# How can I simulate an image load event in AngularJS/Jasmine unit test?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image, events, jasmine

I'm trying to unit test a simple directive which looks as follows:

```
angular.module('blog').directive('imageOnLoad', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, fn) {

            element.bind('load', function() {
                scope.$emit('resizeContent');
            });

        }
    };
});
```

The two things I can see that I need to test here are that it binds to the image load event, which in turn emits the resizeContent event.

I have the following in my unit test - currently just testing the event binding:

```
describe('imageOnLoad', function() {

  beforeEach(module('blog'));

  var scope,compile, element;

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope,$compile) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    compile = $compile;

    var elementString = '<img ng-src="123.jpg" image-on-load />';
    element = $compile(elementString)(scope);
  }));

  it('should bind to the load event of the image', function() {

    spyOn(element, 'bind').andCallThrough();

    expect(element.bind).toHaveBeenCalled();

  });
});
```

My problem: The load event never seems to fire. My first guess is that it's because the 123.jpg image doesn't exist - and if so, my question is how to go about mocking that so I don't have to carry a physical image file in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
element = $compile(elementString)(scope);
```

Try right after that line - that should work:

```
element.trigger('load');
```

Testing jQuery noodles is not much good idea btw.

Comment: No such luck I'm afraid. Still `✖ should bind to the load event of the image`. Not sure what you mean about testing jQuery noodles. All I'm trying to do is detect when an image has loaded so I can hook into that process. I have to resize columns after content is loaded. Suggestions welcome though.

Comment: This may have put me on the right track though - it is now triggering the event (tested with and without using console.log('foo')). I just need to work out how to get the test to pass. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Got it working, it was also an issue of the order in which I set it out. It implicitly tests for the image load event bind by calling it. Here's the working code:

```
describe('imageOnLoad', function() {

  beforeEach(module('blog'));

  var scope,compile, element;

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope,$compile) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    compile = $compile;

    element = angular.element('<img ng-src="123.jpg" image-on-load />');
    $compile(element)(scope);
  }));

  it('should emit the resizeContent signal when the load event occurs', function() {

    spyOn(scope, '$emit');
    element.trigger('load');
    expect(scope.$emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith('resizeContent');

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate load event by selecting the image element and call the **triggerEventHandler** with whatever event you would like.

For example here is an image

```
<img hidden [src]="this.imgService.getImage()" (load)="imgLoaded()" />
```

and if you want to emulate the **load event** to test the **imgLoaded()** method you can

```
  it('imgLoaded should be called when image is preloaded', () => {
    spyOn(component, 'imgLoaded').and.callThrough();

    fixture.detectChanges();

    const preloadImage = debugElement.query(
      By.css('img')
    );

    preloadImage.triggerEventHandler('load')

    expect(component.imgLoaded).toHaveBeenCalledOnceWith();
  });
```